# GenericJDBCException catched by wrong part of the try/catch block

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have this block of code:

```
        } catch (HibernateException e) {

        loginAnswer = new LoginCustomerAreaAnswer(999);

        //This function use the error code save inside loginAnswer
        this.logOp.error(logsUtilities.logException(e, "HibernateException"));


    } catch (Exception e) {

        loginAnswer = new LoginCustomerAreaAnswer(997);

        //This function use the error code save inside loginAnswer
        this.logOp.error(logsUtilities.logException(e, "Exception"));


    } finally {
        return loginAnswer;
    }
```

As you can see, I catch first the HibernateException type exception and then the generic Exception.

But when I look into the log file, when I have a org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException exception it is catched like a generic Exception!

Why?, GenericJDBCException it is not "a son" of HibernateException? Would not have to be catched by the HibernateException??

This is an example of my log file

```
2013-05-21 11:01:02 [Level: ERROR]*** Exception: Error code: 997 - Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

I really lost with this, can somebody help me?

Comment: Why isn't it possible? Maybe the first try-catch doesn't throw any exception..

Comment: Yes, it throw an exception, but it is catched by the second catch (the generic exception catcher) instead of the first catcher (HibernateException catcher).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you caught the Spring Exception:

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Comment: I don't know if I really understand you very well. You tell me that the CannotCreateTransactionException it is called before GenericJDBCException ? But the log it is showing me and GenericJDBCException

Comment: How to catch org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException in java it is not catched by hibernateexception

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your constructor:

```
new LoginCustomerAreaAnswer(...)
```

With passed value 997.

Running this code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            throw new GenericJDBCException( "I'm dead", new SQLException() );
        } catch ( HibernateException hex )
        {
            System.err.println( "HibernateException" );
            hex.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            System.err.println( "Exception" );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me, as expected, HibernateException:

```
HibernateException
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: I'm dead
    at com.execon.utils.Test.main(Test.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: That's what I also expected, but it not happens. And I can't found why. I didn't write the code and also I didn't tested, but my work today is try to find what happens and why :(